# Unit testing error in a D program from cmd

Tags: d

I've a text file, called `test.d`, containing following code snippet:

```
import std.array;

bool binarySearch(T)(T[] input, T value)
{
    while(!input.empty)
    {
        auto i = input.length /2;
        auto mod = input[i];
        if(mid > value) input = input[0 .. i];
        else if (mid < value) input = input[i+1 .. $];
        else return true;
    }
    return false;
}

unittest 
{
    assert(binarySearch([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15], 6) == true);
    assert(binarySearch([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15], 5) == false);
}
```

Upon calling `rdmd`, as below:

```
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin>rdmd.exe F:\Test\test.d
```

A window will be opened to say:

```
An app on your PC needs the following feature:

NTVDM
```

and, a weird error would be thrown:

```
std.process.ProcessException@std\process.d(568): Failed to spawn new process (%1 is a 16-bit application. You do not have permissions to execute 16-bit applications. Check your permissions with your system administrator.)
----------------
0x0043D878
0x0042E14C
0x004042AC
0x00404333
0x00437457
0x00437358
0x0042A064
0x74AADEA4 in BaseThreadInitThunk
0x7700055E in RtlInitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount
0x7700052D in RtlInitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount
```

So, I just installed that `NVDTM`, but as I run the snippet, a pop up just asserts that `NVDTM` has stopped working...

What's wrong?...

Comment: That smells wrong.
Try instead:

    F:\Test $ C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\rdmd.exe test.d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has no main function, so the OS has no idea what it is supposed to do with the executable. Rdmd can add a stub for you. Also, it does not run unittests by default.

Use this command to run it:

```
rdmd -unittest --force --main test.d
```

`-unittest` enables unit testing

`--force` forces recompiling, so it does not use the old executable

`--main` adds a stub main